# What could create unix sockets in PHP 8.2 as a side-effect?

Tags: php, unix-socket, resource-leak, connection-leaks

In two of our many PHP pods (we're running under Kubernetes) we have a problem with a Unix socket leak. Our PHP CLI process seems to be opening and not closing many unix sockets, until in an unrelated location PHP crashes with `PHP Warning: stream_select(): You MUST recompile PHP with a larger value of FD_SETSIZE.`

Other pods that we have also have *some* UNIX sockets open, but in small numbers so it's not a problem.

The perplexing thing is that we're not using UNIX sockets for anything. All communication with other processes is purely through TCP/IP. All the sockets are:

- In `ESTABLISHED` state
- `ss -x` says that there have been no data either sent or received on these sockets
- They do not have a file in the filesystem
- `netstat` says that they all have a `RefCount` of `3`, if it means anything
- `ss -xp` also shows, that both ends of each socket are held by the same (one and only) PHP process.

So... for some reason the PHP program is creating UNIX sockets, holding them open, holding on to both ends of that socket (two different file descriptors), and not letting them go.

In addition, there are no calls to `stream_socket_pair` or `socket_create_pair` in the code.

What I gather from this is that these sockets are created as a side-effect of some other PHP built-in function that I'm using. CURL is the primary suspect here, but it's also used plenty in other pods without issues. In fact I can't think of anything that these two pods are doing which others aren't.

**What built-in PHP functions (including functions in extensions that come bundled by default with PHP) could result in an unintentional creation of a UNIX socket pair?**

Added:

`ss -xp` looks like:

```
# ss -xp
Netid               State               Recv-Q               Send-Q                             Local Address:Port                                  Peer Address:Port                   Process
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 481304571                                        * 481304572               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=494))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 480934363                                        * 480934362               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=289))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 480899260                                        * 480899259               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=255))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 480853228                                        * 480853229               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=207))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 478659551                                        * 478659550               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=82))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 481263776                                        * 481263775               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=484))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 481014545                                        * 481014546               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=339))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 480847844                                        * 480847845               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=221))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 479446282                                        * 479446283               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=185))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 479430966                                        * 479430965               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=162))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 481391710                                        * 481391711               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=515))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 481013994                                        * 481013995               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=352))
u_str               ESTAB               0                    0                                              * 480884372                                        * 480884373               users:(("php",pid=7,fd=233))
.... many, may more lines ...
```

Comment: I'd assume TCP connections that have never been closed (client request, curl, etc.)

Comment: @Vivick - But those would show up as TCP/IP connections, not UNIX sockets, I would think.

Comment: Also note that `stream_select` is just the `select` syscall on an array of PHP `stream` resources

Comment: @Vivick - In fact, TCP connections DO show up as such. If I run `ss -p`, then I get, for example: `tcp                ESTAB                   0                   0                                   1.2.3.4:43652                                5.6.7.8:17733                   users:(("php",pid=7,fd=12))`

Comment: Any `stream_socket_client` calls?

Comment: non-blocking stuff in DB extensions seems to use sockets and thus can be used with functions like `stream_select`

Comment: @Vivick - No, no, no, `stream_select` has nothing to do with this. I use it myself in an **unrelated** place in the program. It's the thing that crashes, but only because there are so many simultaneously opened sockets. The question is - what opens all these sockets and doesn't close them? Because I cannot find anything in my code that would open **UNIX** sockets. TCP sockets - yes, sure, plenty. But not UNIX sockets. There isn't a single place in my code that would open a UNIX socket, yet for some reason the process opens hundreds of them over time.

Comment: No, I say that because it causes the file descriptor limit to be reached. The DB extensions do open the sockets when used in non-blocking mode

Comment: Are you using something akin to Swoole?

Comment: @Vivick No, no swoole or other non-blocking db access. I do use curl in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @Vivick Curl was my first suspect too, but other pods use it too in non blocking mode without issues.

Comment: Are all these socks created by pid=7? Is pid=7 the master process or a process created by you?

Comment: @shingo Yes, all by pid=7. There is just one process in the pod and it does not create child processes. Both ends of all the unix sockets are held by this process.

Comment: Have you tried to use `strace`? Since there is just one process.

Comment: just a WAG ... curl does not  release in some versions unless you `unset` the channel.

Comment: @shingo - No. I'll keep that option in mind, but it seems rather tricky and I also can't easily imagine what useful information I might find there. Maybe, if all else fails I'll try this.

Comment: Trace `socket`, so that you know which C function is calling it.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - OK, but does it open a unix domain socket to something without being asked? Like, if I try to open a `https://` url, can it also open a unix socket in addition to a tcp socket?

Comment: @shingo My code is PHP... I mean, yeah, it's probably doable, but would be difficult as heck. I'd probably have to trace through PHP's own sources too. As I said - I'll keep this option open as a last resort.

Comment: No, I think it probably won't be difficult as heck. Creating Unix socks will be displayed as `socket(AT_UNIX...` in strace, since you're not using them, if you see any call, it is the culprit. With stacktrace, you can find out the relevant C function.

Comment: @shingo - Umm... I'll see the relevant C function, yes... but it'll be inside PHP itself (or one of its extensions). Or, knowing how advanced PHP is these days, it could also be some dynamically generated assembly code. At any case, how do I then trace it back to my PHP code?

Comment: @shingo - Ok, seems like there will be no need for that. Through experimentation I found that the socket pairs are created by curl whenever I make web requests. So far only a single pair, but I'm positive that adding real load and many requests in parallel (like in the affected pods) could produce multiple pairs. The real question is - why is it doing that at all, when I'm making http requests, not unix socket requests? Also it only happens on Kubernetes, and not on my local machine .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer myself. Posting here to help whoever next comes along. The culprit is... **drumroll**... CURL. In particular, `curl_multi_init()` in PHP 8.2 opens a pair of UNIX sockets, presumably for some sort of cross-thread synchronization.

Here's a piece of code that reproduces it:

```
$handles = [];

for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
    $handles[] = curl_multi_init();

echo "Sleeping...";
sleep(10); // Here we have 20 unix sockets open

foreach ($handles as $h)
    curl_multi_close($h); // According to PHP docs, this doesn't do anything in PHP 8, but it's good style anyway.

$handles = [];
echo "Sleeping again...";
sleep(10); // Here we have 2 unix sockets open... because the $h variable still holds the last handle

echo "Goodbye!";
```

I do not know why this behavior isn't present on my local computer. Perhaps it has something to do with the specific CURL or PHP version. In particular:

I have PHP 8.2.13 with CURL 8.5.0 (this doesn't have a problem) while the Kubernetes pod has PHP 8.2.16 with CURL 7.88.1 (this has a problem).

If someone knows why this doesn't happen on my machine, please let me know!

OK, now just to hunt down my own `CurlMultiHandle` leak - that's a much more manageable task and outside the scope of this question.